SQL via JDBC fails on MSSQL Server with BEGIN TRAN
Running this SQL via JDBC on MSSQL works as expected:
UPDATE costcenter
SET    updatetimestamp = Getdate(),
       [de] = 'CostCenterName',
       [en] = 'CostCenterName_en'
WHERE  [customerid] = 'abcd'
       AND [principal] = '1' 

But running this SQL with a Transaction fails:
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS (SELECT [customerid],
                  [principal],
                  [companycode],
                  [costcenter]
           FROM   costcenter
           WHERE  [customerid] = 'abcd'
                  AND [principal] = '1')
  BEGIN
      UPDATE costcenter
      SET    updatetimestamp = Getdate(),
             [de] = 'CostCenterName',
             [en] = 'CostCenterName_en'
      WHERE  [customerid] = 'abcd'
             AND [principal] = '1'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO costcenter
                  (inserttimestamp,
                   updatetimestamp,
                   customerid,
                   principal,
                   companycode,
                   costcenter,
                   de,
                   en)
      VALUES      (Getdate(),
                   Getdate(),
                   'abcd',
                   '1',
                   '1',
                   '0',
                   'CostCenterName',
                   'CostCenterName_en')
  END
COMMIT TRAN 

The reported error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'
Running this SQL on MS SQL Management Studio works.
So I think it has to do with the JDBC-Connection.

which error exactly and this lokks more like a thread for stackoverflow

Have you tried adding statement terminators?

(Terrible spelling in my previous comment) I suspect that the text is truncated, hence the incorrect syntax. Look at the API level if you can see some max length involved. Also pick up the command submitted to SQL using XE or Profiler to see the truth.
